# "className did not match" in local dev only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, babeljs, styled-components

I am developing an application using NextJS, React, and Styled Components. My application looks/works fine in production, but when I am running it locally for development the components used in `_app.tsx` are unstyled and I see the `className did not match` error in the browser console.

- NextJS 12.0.7
- React 17.0.2
- Styled Components 5.3.3
- babel-plugin-styled-components 2.0.2

Here's my `.babelrc` file:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [["styled-components", { "ssr": true }], "superjson-next"]
}
```

Why is this only happening when I run the app locally and how do I fix It?

[_app.tsx](https://github.com/alexpaxton/solring/blob/main/pages/_app.tsx)

Production:
[image: Production Screenshot]

Local Development:
[image: Local Development Screenshot]

Here's the code for the `NavBar.tsx` component that is having rendering issues:

```
import { CreateDeckButton } from 'components/CreateDeckButton'
import { Button, colors } from 'components/ui'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { FC } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useMe } from 'utils'

export const NavBar: FC = () => {
  const { me, isLoading, isError } = useMe()
  const { asPath } = useRouter()

  function getUrl(url: string) {
    return asPath === '/' ? url : `${url}?returnTo=${asPath}`
  }

  let actions = (
    <Button href={getUrl('/api/auth/login')} as="a" variant="neutral">
      Login
    </Button>
  )

  if (isLoading) {
    actions = <span>Loading...</span>
  }

  if (isError) {
    actions = (
      <Button href={getUrl('/api/auth/login')} as="a" variant="neutral">
        Login
      </Button>
    )
  }

  if (me) {
    actions = (
      <>
        <p>
          Logged in as <strong>{`@${me.handle}`}</strong>
        </p>
        <Button href={getUrl('/api/auth/logout')} as="a" variant="primary">
          Logout
        </Button>
      </>
    )
  }

  return (
    <Header>
      <Left>
        <Link href="/">
          <Logo>Sol Ring</Logo>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/decks">
          <Button as="a" variant="neutral">
            Decks
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/gatherer">
          <Button as="a" variant="neutral">
            Gatherer
          </Button>
        </Link>
        <CreateDeckButton />
      </Left>
      <Actions>{actions}</Actions>
    </Header>
  )
}

const Header = styled.header`
  flex: 0 0 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ${colors.n1};
  color: ${colors.n7};
  padding: 0 30px;
  justify-content: space-between;
`

const Left = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  & > button,
  & > a {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
`

const Logo = styled.h1`
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 16px;
`

const Actions = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  & > button,
  & > a {
    margin-left: 16px;
  }
`
```

Comment: So what do the components in _app.tsx look like?

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ https://github.com/alexpaxton/solring/blob/main/pages/_app.tsx

Comment: [edit] the code into the question dont just post a link to a repo and expect others to sift your code

Comment: @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ that's fair. I added some screenshots and code snippets in the main question. Not 100% sure what is relevant / not relevant here but I hope it is helpful in finding an answer

Answer (score 1):

you can ditch babelrc altogether with Next 12, then you'll be able to use the full power of the SWC Compiler. Try this config out in your `next.config.js` file and delete your .babelrc file

```js
const { withSuperjson } = require("next-superjson");

require("eslint-config-next/parser");

const {
  env: { ANALYZE }
} = process;

// @ts-check
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 **/

module.exports = withSuperjson()({
  webpack(config, options) {
    config.experiments = config.experiments || {};
    // allows for async imports within fuctions
    config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true;
    return config;
  },
  swcMinify: true,
  webpack5: true,
  sourceMaps: {
    productionBrowserSourceMaps: true
  },
  experimental: {
    // ssr and displayName are configured by default
    styledComponents: true,
  },
  images: {
    formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"],
    domains: [
      "avatars.githubusercontent.com",
      "secure.gravatar.com",
      "en.gravatar.com",
      "unsplash.com",
      "images.unsplash.com",
      "tailwindui.com",
      "gravatar.com",
      "images.unsplash.com",
      "lh3.googleusercontent.com"
    ]
  },
  reactStrictMode: true
});

console.log("[next.config.js]: ", JSON.stringify(module.exports, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my issue by changing my `.babelrc` file to the following:

```
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": ["styled-components", "superjson-next"]
}
```